# How to write testcases SymbolLayer on MapBox Android

Tags: android, testing, mapbox, testcase

I am writing a MapBox application on Android. But I do not know how to write test-cases for it.

Ex, I want to assert that Map contains Icons

How can I write test-cases?

Thank

Comment: Since Mapbox Maps SDK For android uses native code, you will have to use an instrumentation test to actually verify the contents of a Map. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Have you seen the tests the SDK has in https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/tree/master/platform/android/MapboxGLAndroidSDKTestApp/src/androidTest/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk ?

Comment: Thanks for your response,

Comment: I am using Expresso and uiautomator to search for icons (in SymbolLayer) on a map, but both of them cannot catch anything. I am also trying to use  "Layout Inspector", and "uiautomatorviewer.bat" to look for Icons but I cannot find anything.

Base on my understand, Mapbox draws all Icons on a map in backend and returns only one Image object to frontend. Is it right?

I also use google map SDK, uiautomator for testing.
One way I search markers in a map:
uiDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().descriptionContains("marker title"));
Is there any similar method on MapBox?

Thanks